# How to convert a msql connection to mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

Can someone please just help tell me how to make this connection work on xampp. I just want an answer please and i will definitely find out later why it works. for now its just to get through the connection. I am having error Call to undefined function mysql_connect.

**Can someone just please correct it all for me my code is.**

```
 class Installer{
function ExtractSql($host,$user,$pass,$db,$data){
    $conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    if(!$conn){
        return 'Error connecting to mysql!';
    }else{
        $database = mysql_select_db($db);
        if(!$database){
            return 'Error connecting to database!';
        }else{
            $query = null;
            foreach($data as $sql_line){
              if(trim($sql_line) != "" && strpos($sql_line, "--") === false){
                $query .= $sql_line;
                if (substr(rtrim($query), -1) == ';'){
                  $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
                  $query = null;
                }
              }
            }
              file_put ba bla bla

           }
         }
      }
```

I can get pass line 4 by inserting a mysqli connection

but I got hooked on line 17 which is.

```
     $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
```

I have done a bit of research correcting each lines and a different error always occurs, sosme saying, this line should have atleast 2paramater, only one given in ...

I will appreciate if i dont have to spend time to research on it now(but I will later). I just want to pass through it now..
Cheers.

Comment: Someone will correct your code, but not on SO.

Comment: Just don't panic. Go to the PHP manual and read how MySQLi works. Try some examples, and then look at your code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All mysqli methods require the connection as parameter. For example, for `mysqli_query` you need to use:

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Alternatively, you can create a MySQLi object and use that:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass);
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

Even better, forget about MySQLi and convert to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Also, the answer to this question was just one manual lookup away, try to put in some effort yourself next time!

Comment: Yes, I think, given a choice, I would choose PDO. It's potentially a bit more flexible.